# onclick page go to homepage without any absolute path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click on link and I want to go to the page on home page by it self

```
<a onclick="javascript:GoToHomePage()" href="javascript:void(0)">Home page</a>
```

function is

```
function GoToHomePage()
{
    window.location = 'default.aspx';   
}
```

but i want the url of page www.testtest.com instead of www.testtest.com/default.aspx

I can't even give the absolute path like www.testtest.com as it's a portal and same page coming in few more portals.

Comment: What's the point of using javascript to do this? `<a href="/">Home page</a>` is much, much simpler.

Comment: i cant remove old code as some condition is coming in every case

Answer (score 28, accepted):

following code will take you to '//www.testtest.com/'

```
   function GoToHomePage()
  {
    window.location = '/';   
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
window.location = '/';
```

Executing this code will send your visitor directly to the root of your website.

Comment: thnx for answer :-) and for explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need

```
window.location = '/default.aspx';
```

or

```
window.location = '/';
```

(not sure of your goal)

The '/' means "the root of the domain".

Answer (score 0):

Add `/` before `default.aspx` and it should take you to `home page`

```
function GoToHomePage()
{
    window.location = '/default.aspx';   
}
```

Comment: its not working its redirecting to www.testtest.com/default.aspx and i want redirect to www.testtest.com

Comment: Then change it to `window.location = '/'; `

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use href instead of onclick due to various obvious reasons:

```
<a href="/">Home page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, as suggested by `@Olly Hodgson`:

```
<a href="/">Home page</a>
```